# Total friends who posted a Like or comment on the posts generated by app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been asked to come up with this metric. I'm not sure of the thinking behind it maybe that a facebook friend can comment more than once.

But i have looked through the post api docs and can't think of how i would measure it. I also looked through facebook insights and can not find anything. Any suggestions on how to measure this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of likes for a post by using this FQL query

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id=" " // Object ID can be the post ID, that you received when a post is generated
```

You will receive the ID of all the people who have liked the post and you can check these ID's againts the ID's of the users friends. That way you can calculate the number of friends who have liked a certain post

Reference for [like fql table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/)

And similarly for comments you can use the following FQL query

```
SELECT comments,username,text,fromid FROM comment WHERE object_id=" " // Object ID can be the post ID
```

Similarly for the above query you will get the following data.
And you will easily get the ID of the user who has commented on the post and you can check it againts the users friends ID's.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "comments": [
      ], 
      "username": "", 
      "text": "<3", 
      "fromid": 100003768234756
    }, 
    {
      "comments": [
      ], 
      "username": "Anonymous User", 
      "text": "So True <3", 
      "fromid": 1770337460
    }, 
    {
      "comments": [
      ], 
      "username": "Anonymous User", 
      "text": "That is the truth.......", 
      "fromid": 1165407722
    }, 
    {
      "comments": [
      ], 
      "username": "", 
      "text": "<3", 
      "fromid": 537035838
    }, 
    {
      "comments": [
      ], 
      "username": "Anonymous User", 
      "text": "So do u my love", 
      "fromid": 100003542817498
    }
  ]
}
```

Reference for [Comments fql table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/)

Track every post you make, for every user.
When you make a post on Facebook via your app you get a post ID for every post, so you just need to keep a track of every post generated for each user, so that you can get the number of likes made on every post

Comment: well this is obvious but thats not what the question asked

Comment: and what about  finding the posts generated by an app?

Comment: when you make a post on Facebook via your app you get a post ID for every post, so you just need to keep a track of every post generated for each user